# Launch main ViewController when home button is pressesd

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am doing an Objective-C app which has several independient ViewControllers.
I want to show my main ViewController when user pulses home button and app goes to background mode.
All solutions I've found is for navigation controllers.
How can I launch (and where) a ViewController in this case?

Thanks

**SOLVED**:
Finally I solved this issue adding in AppDelegate:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.

    ViewController *viewController=[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
    self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should register for the `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` in the main viewcontroller. When the notification is posted you should pop the navigation stack to the main viewcontroller.

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Alternatively if this isn't the root viewcontroller you should use:

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:self animated:YES];
```